# Content / fields of newly created single don't show up

Tags: entries, control-panel, error, upgrades

After a fresh install of Craft on my localhost, two problems occur:

1) The modal window to upgrade Craft only says *"An unknown error occured."*

2) **Newly created singles are not editable**, the edit pane stays empty with no input fields at all.

I looked into craft.log and there seems to be an issue with CHttpRequest.php, but I can't say if this is a local config problem or if it's a bug:

```
******************************************************************************************************
2015/02/25 13:08:35 [error] [php] Cannot modify header information - headers already sent (/Users/me/Sites/test-dev-craft/app/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php:1392)
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/me/Sites/test-dev-craft/app/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php(1329): Craft\CookieCollection->remove()
#1 /Users/me/Sites/test-dev-craft/app/services/UserSessionService.php(1170): Craft\CookieCollection->add()
#2 /Users/me/Sites/test-dev-craft/app/framework/web/auth/CWebUser.php(203): Craft\UserSessionService->renewCookie()
#3 /Users/me/Sites/test-dev-craft/app/services/UserSessionService.php(91): Craft\UserSessionService->init()
#4 /Users/me/Sites/test-dev-craft/app/framework/base/CModule.php(387): Craft\UserSessionService->init()
#5 /Users/me/Sites/test-dev-craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(569): Craft\WebApp->getComponent()
#6 /Users/me/Sites/test-dev-craft/app/framework/base/CModule.php(103): Craft\WebApp->getComponent()
#7 /Users/me/Sites/test-dev-craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(160): Craft\WebApp->__get()
#8 /Users/me/Sites/test-dev-craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(180): Craft\WebApp->processRequest()
#9 /Users/me/Sites/test-dev-craft/app/index.php(62): Craft\WebApp->run()
#10 /Users/me/Sites/test.dev/index.php(19): require_once()
REQUEST_URI=/test.dev/index.php/admin/actions/tasks/getRunningTaskInfo
```

This is my local setup:

- Mac OS X 10.10.2
- Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/1.0.2
- PHP Version 5.6.5
- MySQL 5.6.22 - Homebrew

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I've also had this problem, running from localhost. Mac OS X 10.10.3
PHP 5.6.1
Mysql 5.5.38

Comment: I'm getting this error locally too. PHP 5.6

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue and found a solution that worked for my setup:  https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/9016/831

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

That error means that something, somewhere has already started outputting to the browser before Yii/Craft/PHP expected it to happen.

99% of the time, it's some whitespace or unintended character that got added to the beginning of one of Craft's files.

Try doing a fresh upload of all of Craft's files and see if that helps.

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks a lot for your answer. I already tried a completely fresh install in a new folder with a fresh db etc. The only files I touched were the craft/config/db.php and the public .htaccess for the standard index.php rewrite. Any other suggestions? Maybe it's an encoding issue?

Comment: If you enable devMode, does any other helpful information get logged?

Comment: DevMode did not show anything of help – as far as I can tell. The only thing that worked was setting _display_errors_ to _Off_ in php.ini. Not my preferred solution, but it works for now…