# Error when trying to test Craft Pro on .dev

Tags: install, license

I have a fresh Craft install set up locally at mysite.craft.dev. I would like to start building out the features offered by the pro license, but when I click the "Show me" link in the footer, I get "An unknown error occurred."

I am seeing this error in craft.log: 
`015/04/03 17:13:55 [error] [php] Cannot modify header information - headers already sent (/Users/aaron/Sites/mysite/craft/app/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php:1392)`

In potentially related news, tasks do not seem to be behaving correctly.

Anyone ever experience this before? Any help is appreciated :)

[image]

Comment: There [similar question](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/8384/125) already. Unfortunately it's still more or less unsolved.

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution! I had my local environment setup with homebrew following [this article's instructions](https://echo.co/blog/os-x-1010-yosemite-local-development-environment-apache-php-and-mysql-homebrew). After looking at the php error logs, I uncommented `always_populate_raw_post_data = -1` in the php.ini file found in /usr/local/etc/php/5.6.

I then restarted the brew services with `brew services restart php56` (install brew services by tapping gapple/services with `brew tap gapple/services`) and restarted apache with `apachectl restart`.

That did the trick!

Comment: I had to go back to php55 to solve my issues, thanks for the info!